# PANIC:Could not open: droid17 emulator launching error on ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, eclipse, ubuntu

I have installed eclipse using this wikihow tutorial

http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Android-on-Ubuntu-Linux-with-Eclipse-IDE

Everything is alright but when it comes to launching apk on AVD this error comes:

```
[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - First] Android Launch!

[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - First] adb is running normally.

[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - First] Performing com.example.first.MainActivity activity launch

[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - First] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 'droid17'

[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - First] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'droid17'

[2014-07-21 20:51:26 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: droid17
```